# How do i send an extra string info OnClick?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a for loop creating my main home page cards , i have 3 models
Image ,title and body
the idea is to get the specific info for each card that I'm pressing on his "view " button .

I'be been using django with python , and I'm trying to make like a news website where you see the title on the cards on the home page and when you click them you get a scroll bar with the full info about the arctical ,
the problem is that because I'm looping trough the database to get all the cards , when I press on the "View" button doesn't mattet which one I get the body of the text that Is last on the List.

```
<div class="row">
        {%for job in jobs.all%}

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
           <img class ="card-img-top" src ="{{job.image.url}}" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{job.title}}</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable"
                  >
                    View
                  </button>




                  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Full artical</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                          {{job.body}}

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are producing multiple nodes that all have ID `exampleModalScrollable`, which is not quite legal. Not sure which front-end library you're depending on, but I believe you want to have the `data-target` in the button align with the `id` of the modal for each item. The easiest is to use the model's ID; something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#job-modal-{{job.id}}">
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="job-modal-{{job.id}}" tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{job.title}}" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer , i understand what you're saying and it make sense but now when i changed it the scroll bar doesn't open , I think it's not recognizing the data target as the id of the scroll bar Edit- never mind All i needed to do is to move the # Thank you !